# Storing multilple values with correspond to a key in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I am beginner to java and exploring the collections I want a map of Map in which key will be of integer type and its will contains value as ulitimately I want to store in Map like..

```
key  Value
1     abc,def,ght
2     fdr,ute,ytr
3     rds,yhj,lgt
```

please how can I store this in map in java.

Comment: you can try Map<Integer, List<String>>

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a **Multimap**.

The Guava library has an implementation for this so you don't need to implement it yourself.

You can look for details [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained).

If you don't like that you can simply use a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multimap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
someList.add("abc");
someList.add("def");
someList.add("ght");
multimap.put(1, someList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map<Integer, String[]>` or `Map<Integer, List<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `Map<Integer, Set<String>`, where the value of your map is a set of all the values the key points to.

Fortunately, there are several good implementations of such structures out there in 3rd party libraries, like Apache Commons Collections' [MultiHashMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a try  using

```
Map<Integer, List<String>>
```